# Blanks in the denominator of a replacement rule

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 7.0 seems to dislike having blanks in the denominator.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Input:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(*Without blanks:*)
a^2 / b^2 /. a^2 / b^2 -> d
(*with:*)
a^2 / b^2 /. a^c_ / b^c_ -> d
(*Without blanks:*)
a^2 / b^2 /. (a / b)^2 -> d
(*With:*)
a^2 / b^2 /. (a / b)^c_ -> d
(*Without blanks:*)    
a^2 / b^2 /. a^2 * b^(-2) -> d
(*With:*)
a^2 / b^2 /. a^c_ * b^(-c_) -> d
```

Output:

```
d
a^2/b^2
d
a^2/b^2
d
a^2/b^2
```

I'm trying to work this for a more complicated problem.  The substitution that I want to make is in an expression of the form:

```
(a ^ c_. * Coefficient1_. / b ^ c_. / Coefficient2_.)  +  (a ^ d_. * Coefficient3_. / b ^ d_. / Coefficient4_.)
```

Where the coefficients may involve sums, products, and quotients **of variables that may or may not include`a` and `b`.**

**Possibly relevant:**

The FullForm shows that the power in the denominator is stored as a product of -1 and c:

Input:

```
FullForm[a^2/b^2]
FullForm[a^c_/b^c_]
FullForm[ (a / b)^2 ]
FullForm[(a / b)^c_ ]
FullForm[a^2 * b^(-2) ]
FullForm[a^c_ * b^(-c_)]
```

Output:

```
Times[Power[a,2],Power[b,-2]]
Times[Power[a,Pattern[c,Blank[]]],Power[b,Times[-1,Pattern[c,Blank[]]]]]
Times[Power[a,2],Power[b,-2]]
Power[Times[a,Power[b,-1]],Pattern[c,Blank[]]]
Times[Power[a,2],Power[b,-2]]
Times[Power[a,Pattern[c,Blank[]]],Power[b,Times[-1,Pattern[c,Blank[]]]]]
```

Edit: Bolded change to my actual case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with [everything Mr.Wizard wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168040/blanks-in-the-denominator-of-a-replacement-rule/7169730#7169730). Having said that, a replacement rule that would work in this specific case would be:

```
a^2/b^2 /. (Times[Power[a,c_],Power[b,e_]]/; e == -c )-> d
```

or

```
a^2/b^2 /.  (a^c_ b^e_/; e == -c )-> d
```

Note that I added the constraint `/; e == -c` so that I effectively have a `-c_` without actually creating the corresponding `Times[-1,c_]` expression

Comment: Rather clever.  Did you keep the explicit full function names for clarity?  I think you should include the normal form as well.

Comment: Yeah, I used that to illustrate the structural equality of this expression to the ones at the bottom of the question. Added the compact form too. Thanks!

Comment: Heheh. I hope that +1 on my comment in @rcollyer's answer was from you :)

Comment: @maberib Actually it wasn't me, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this. I missed your comment and I'll delete my answer after you've read this.

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking you should try to avoid doing *mathematical* manipulation using `ReplaceAll` which is a *structural* tool.

As opposed to `FullForm`, I will use `TreeForm` to illustrate these expressions:

```
a^2/b^2   // TreeForm
a^c_/b^c_ // TreeForm
```

[image]
[image]

You can see that while these expressions are *mathematically* similar, they are *structurally* quite different.  You may be able to hammer out a functioning replacement rule for a specific case, but you will usually be better off using the [Formula Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FormulaManipulation.html) (or [Polynomial Algebra](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PolynomialAlgebra.html)) tools that *Mathematica* provides.

If you carefully describe the mathematical manipulation you wish to achieve, I will attempt to provide a better solution.

---

As belisarius humorously points out in a comment, trying to force *Mathematica* to "see" or display expressions the way you do is often largely futile.  This is one of the reasons that the opening statement above is true.

Comment: +1, good point. Use patterns for manipulation if you absolutely must, primarily because there is no way to check them. You can make mathematically absurd changes with using `Replace` extremely easily.

Comment: +1 But the OP should be warned that trying to force Mma to write formulas the way humans usually do is (sometimes) like trying to feed a statue.

Comment: @belisarius I added a note; does that cover what you meant, or would you care to edit the answer and say something more?

Comment: @Mr. I think it is Ok now. Every Mma user has been there at least once and hopefully learned to let the System go by its own ways.

Comment: @belisarius, or twice, or 12 times. I periodically fall into that trap.

Comment: I would argue that there are times that making structural changes are an absolute must. For instance, if you want to `Collect` real and imaginary terms of an equation. Usually this requires the replacement of `a + I b` with something like `a + q b`, collecting on `q`, then resetting `q-> I`.

Comment: @rcollyer surely there are times that structural tools are appropriate for mathematical expressions.  However, from the OP's description of "a more complicated problem" I think that is unlikely in this case.  I did not intend to declare this as a rigid rule, but rather I used phrases like "generally speaking" and "usually be better."

Comment: For those who have too much time on their hands and would like to waste some, and to complement this nice answer, I recommend this Mathgroup thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5cfb8ae645fa5bc1

Comment: +1 For introducing me to treeform.  I have the frustration with Mathematica that it's shiny interface obfuscates errors making them hard to diagnose.  This seems like a good way to use that same shiny interface to debug.

Comment: @Maberib for that end of things, please also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5459735/

Answer (score 4):

The primary reason `a^2 / b^2 /. a^c_ / b^c_ -> d` doesn't work is your using [`Rule` (`->`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) not [`RuleDelayed` (`:>`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html). The second reason, as you found with `FullForm`, is that `a/b` is interpreted as `Times[a, Power[b,-1]]`, so it is best to not use division.  Making these changes,

```
a^2 / b^2 /. a^n_ b^m_ :> {n,m}
```

returns `{2, -2}`.  Usually, you'll want to have a [default value](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html), so that

```
a / b^2 /. a^n_. b^m_. :> {n,m}
```

returns `{1,-2}`.

**Edit**: to ensure that the two exponents are equal, requires the addition of the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) (/;)

```
a^2 / b^2 /. a^n_. b^m_. /; n == m :> n
```

Note: by using `_.` this will also catch `a/b`.

Comment: Switching to DelayedRule has no effect on any of the examples I provided.  

`a^2 / b^2 /. a^c_ b^e_ -> d` Works, but the problem is that it doesn't ensure that the top and bottom are of the same power. 

Although I suppose that could be fixed with a condition: `a^2 / b^2 /. a^c_ b^e_ /; c == -e -> d` .  Still feels like a bit of a bug to me.

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider ensuring that they were the same power, and it makes it a pain. I'd probably go with the condition, myself.

Comment: @rcollyer I think I saw a good answer or comment by Leonid about using patterns to match denominators. I can't find it right now.

Comment: @belisarius, looked for it, too, could not find it.

Comment: @Leonid, do you have a take on this?

Comment: I vaguely remember some discussion on the topic, but could not find anything related in my answers or comments on SO. On general grounds, for expressions of any complexity, exact matching with blanks becomes very fragile - I can only add my voice to the answer of @Mr.Wizard.